# python jarvis not running part2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi there in the code below wikipedia and Youtube seems to be working.But when ever i try to open google Chrome it opens Youtube instead.or whenever i sat 'how handsome am i'it opens youtube instead.How can i solve this issue.How can i open youtube in google Chrome using this python code and my voice.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak('Good Morning Sir')
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak('Good Afternoon sir')
    else:
        speak('Good Evening sir')    

        speak('I am Jarvis')   
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print('Recognizing...')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:

        print('say that again pls sir')
        return "None"
    return query       


if __name__ == "__main__":
   wishMe()
   while True:
       query = takeCommand().lower()


       if 'wikipedia' in query:
           speak('Searching wikipedia')
           query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
           results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
           speak("According to Wikipedia")
           print(results)
           speak(results)
       elif  'open Youtube in query':
           webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
       elif 'how handsome am i in query':
           speak('you are very Handsome sir')  
       elif 'open Google in query':
           googlePath = ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
           os.startfile(googlePath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you over missed something from your last question, for checking if youtube, google, or how handsome am I, are in query, use  `elif 'open youtube' in query: # do not put 'in query' inside of single quotes`

remember, do not put 'in query' inside of quotes,

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below; you made a small mistake: it should be `elif 'open youtube' in query:` , not `elif 'open youtube in query':`.

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak('Good Morning Sir')
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak('Good Afternoon sir')
    else:
        speak('Good Evening sir')    

        speak('I am Jarvis')   
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print('Recognizing...')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:

        print('say that again pls sir')
        return "None"
    return query       


if __name__ == "__main__":
   wishMe()
   while True:
       query = takeCommand().lower()


       if 'wikipedia' in query:
           speak('Searching wikipedia')
           query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
           results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
           speak("According to Wikipedia")
           print(results)
           speak(results)
       elif  'open Youtube' in query:
           webbrowser.open('youtube.com')
       elif 'how handsome am i, in query:
           speak('you are very Handsome sir')  
       elif 'open Google' in query:
           googlePath = ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
           os.startfile(googlePath)
```